# Warning: Undefined array key "rating" in /var/www/html/dynamic/vendor/magento/framework/Setup/Declaration/Schema/Db/SchemaBuilder.php on line 153

Tags: magento2.4.6

This is showing after magneto upgrade how can I fix it. I have just upgrade it from magento version 2.4.3 to 2.4.6

Comment: Could you please add some more information? From what to which version did you upgrade? When exactly does this error happen? What have you tried so far?

Comment: yes , I have try to upgrade magento 2.4.3 to latest version upgrade successfully but when try to run magento steup:upgrade its not work showing error that time.

Comment: I have just remove all third party extension but still this error showing

Answer (score 0):

It has been solved , there is something issue under magento table data import. second time import again using create new database the problem has been solved .